# Issues placing an angular heart shaped CSS object centered responsive under running text

Tags: css

I tried accomplish the following:

- load a pattern as background image.
- have a angular shaped heart with a low opacity at the top of the page centered behaving responsively.
- text blocks should flow over the backgroundimage as well as the heart.

i've already built something: http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/aIkDH  - but there are one or two problems left:

## Issues:

- margin: 0 auto doesn't work to center the heart. i suppose margin refers to the width of the heart selector which is half of the width of the heart:after selector. is there a way to center it properly anyway?
- even that the size values are set in em the heart doesn't scale down even that the viewport is set to: @viewport{
      width:device-width;
      zoom:1;
   }

## Flaws:

- Is a wrapper div (.pack) absolutely necessary or is there a more elegant way with less elements?
- Is there a more elegant way to build the heart (but the angular design is on purpose ;) ) or is the before and after solution ok?

Thanks Ralf

Answer (score 0):

One of these two should help with centering.

```
#heart {
    display: block;
}
```

or

```
#heart {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: hmmmm they have no effect. tried it individually on a test case too but they stick to the left side: http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/lxDyJ